# JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: MyClass["underlyingValue"])

Tags: java, gwt, objectmapper, json-serialization

I have a POJO class extending `net.sf.gilead.pojo.gwt.LightEntity`. I am not able to serialize the POJO object to JSON string using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj)`. I am getting this error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Direct self-reference leading to cycle 
(through reference chain: com.example.MyClass["underlyingValue"])
```

Noticed that the LightEntity class has this method:

```
public Object getUnderlyingValue() {
   return this;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about to try to override this method in your `MyClass` class and add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation?

Example:

```
public class MyClass extends LightEntity {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public Object getUnderlyingValue() {
        return super.getUnderlyingValue();
    }

}
```